# "this" losing scope of its parent, Core?

Tags: javascript

This works perfectly fine in node,js, but in the browser it seems to be flunking. Whenever I call `Core.handleLogin` from `Events`, `this` from within `Core.handleLogin` points to a `Socket` (socket.io). Can I get the JavaScript to set the default `this` of a prototype to be its parent, like in **node.js**?

**CORE.JS**

```
/*
 *  CLIENT.
 *  THIS IS THE CORE/PARENT MODULE OF THE GAME.
 */

(function(){
function Core(client){
    //game modules
    this.client = client;

    //load game modules
    this.Events = new Game.Events(this, client);
    this.Map = new Game.Map(this);
    this.Player = new Game.Player(this);
    this.Canvas = new Game.Canvas(this, document.getElementById('game'));
}

Core.prototype.handleLogin = function(data){
    console.log(this); <------------------------------ I WANT THIS TO THE CORE OBJECT

    if(data){
        this.Player.username = data.username;
        this.Player.rights = data.rights;

        console.log('Logged in.');
    }else{
        console.log('Failed login.');
    }
}

Game.Core = Core;
})();
```

**EVENTS.JS**

```
/*
 *  CLIENT
 */

(function(){
function Events(Core,client){
    this.Core = Core;
    this.client = client;

    client.on('connect', function(){
        console.log('Connected to the server.');

        client.emit('login', Core.getCookie('session'));
    });
    client.on('loggedIn', Core.handleLogin); <---------------------------------------
}

Game.Events = Events;
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing because you say you want `this` to be `Core`, but `Core` is your constructor function.  It is not an instance of your object.  So, you probably need something like this somewhere:

```
 var obj = new Core(xxx);
```

And, then you can solve your event handling issue with something like this:

```
client.on('loggedIn', obj.handleLogin.bind(obj));
```

That's because when you do this:

```
client.on('loggedIn', obj.handleLogin);
```

you are getting a reference to the `handleLogin` function and passing that as your event handler.  When the loggedIn event occurs and it calls handleLogin, it is called without any object reference.  When a function, any function even one defined as a method is called without any object reference, then `this` is set to either the global object or to undefined (in strict mode).  That's what is happening in your case.

This would the same situation as:

```
var f = obj.handleLogin;
f();
```

When you do that, handleLogin will end up getting called with no object reference and thus `this` not set to `obj`.

So, to get around that, you have to create some other way to reconnect your function with the right object reference.  There are actually multiple ways to do this, but as long as you don't need to support old IE, `.bind()` is one of the simplest.  Here's another way:

```
var obj = new Core(xxx);
client.on('loggedIn', function() {
    return obj.handleLogin.apply(Core, arguments);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is your Core object? I see a constructor but I don't think you meant that to be the object. You probably want to write `var theCore = new Core();` somewhere. Then call it with:

```
  client.on('loggedIn', function () {
     Core.handleLogin.apply(theCore);
  } );
```

or simply:

```
 theCore.handleLogin();
```